# VSE: Fade to white via a bloom transition

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I have a video that I'd like to fade out to white by increasing in glow intensity until it is pure white.

Here's an example of a "before" photo ([courtesy of Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/en/motorcycle-chrome-technology-9360/)):

[image: Just an example photo - courtesy of Pixabay]

The problem is that I can't get the Glow effect in the Video Sequence Editor to get any more intense than this:

[image: With glow effect strip added, but not glowy enough]

The above photo is using these settings:

[image: Glow strip settings]

Boost Factor can't be raised above 10, and Blur Distance can't be raised above 20, so I can't reach pure white. Is there a better way to go about achieving this technique?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in the VSE is with an *Add* effect:

1. Add a color strip and animate it's color from black to white (press <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over the color field to insert keyframes)
2. Select both the color strip and your clip and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Effect > Add*.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting the Color Strip because I didn't know what that did until now and I had been preparing solid white or black stills in an image editor like a fool, hehe. Unfortunately since your answer does not use a glow effect I can't mark it as an accepted answer. If glow were used the white would emanate from the brightest points - the headlights in this case. Thanks for teaching me something though.

Comment: @Mentalist Adding a glow strip to the add strip makes it a bit more glowy. If that's still not quite what you're after, is it possible you could provide an animated example showing what you want?

Comment: Here's an example where you can see the glow expanding from the brightest parts. Never mind that this example has color overlays: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_Mr-3JiM9I Here's a second example from a Premiere tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKqaSieGEqk

Comment: It turns out that adding a Glow strip on top of your configuration works to get the desired effect! And with the Glow settings maxed out it doesn't take much lightening of the black color to make it go pure white! So then all that's left to do is tweak the curves on both the Color strip and the Glow strip's Boost Factor from the default  S-curves to something that ramps up faster and faster as it approaches pure white. parameciostudio offered a good answer too and I think while his technique is faster from a workflow perspective, yours yields a slightly higher quality effect. Both are valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply the glow effect by using the Multiply value in the property panel.
You can animate the value from 1 to 20

[image]

You can change the multiply value both on the glow strip and the video clip to combine the effects and to get a complete white image

Comment: I think you mean from 1 to 20 (values below 1 darken it). And just to clarify - this needs to be done on the video strip below the Glow strip, as doing it on the Glow strip has no effect. Still, good observation. It's quick and it works. It didn't eliminate every dark area completely but it got like 99.9% so if the next frame were solid white I'm sure no viewers would notice. I may accept this as the best answer. I will definitely upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the compositor to perform the effect.

Threshold the color to black and white or grayscale with animated color ramp ... with alpha 1 for white and alpha 0 for black.

Blur for smoothness and animate dilation to whiten and widen edges .  You will have created a sequence of white spots on transparency .png images. At some point in the animation they can coalesce into complete if you choose. Then you can place alpha .png images as overlay elsewhere including VSE or Compositor.

Comment: Thanks - I'm in the process of trying this now, but I can't get the compositor to affect my video. It won't show a backdrop either even though I have "Backdrop" checked and a Viewer node is plugged in. Does something have to be changed in the compositor when working with video?

Comment: You may have to hit the render button to trigger the preview node output.